# Writing and Parsing Binary Data in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, io

So i wrote server tcp application with nodejs, here is the code:

**Server Side**

```
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 15010;

// Instruct server to start Listening for incoming connection
function listen() {
  // Start Server
  console.log('Server Started [' + host + ':' + port + ']');

  var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    // Send Connection Success
    socket.write('Success');
    socket.pipe(socket);

    // Server Received a new Connection from Client
    console.log('Client was Connected [' +
      socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort + ']');


    // When Server Received data from Client.
    socket.on('data', function(resp) {
      console.log('We received following data: ' + resp);

      // probably going to tell server whether my Game is about to exit
      // so the server will close the current socket.
      // and also won't caught ECONNRESET exception lol.
    });

    // When Client Connection is Ended.
    socket.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Connected Ended ');

      // Destroy closed socket
      socket.destroy();
    });

    // When Client Connection is Closed.
    socket.on('close', function() {
      console.log('Client was Closed ');

      // Destroy closed socket
      socket.destroy();
    });

    // When Server caught an exception
    socket.on('error', function(ex) {
      // Server will caught an exception if client was disconnected from client side
      // It's appear the server was not expected when client is disconnected.
      // Currently, i will salvage it as much as i can until i find better solution (or this is the best solution(?) lol) but it's doesn't matter for now..
      if (ex.code == 'ECONNRESET') {
        console.log('Ending current session of Client');
      }
    });

  }).listen(port, host);
```

it's work well when handling incoming string data.
However i was wondering how to parse a binary data that received by the server from client.

I am using following code in my game to send data to server:

**Client Side**

```
        // Use memory stream
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Use binary writer also
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(ms);

            // Write int16 (2 bytes)
            writer.Write((short)id);

            // Write int32 (4 bytes)
            writer.Write((int)status);

            // Write int64 (8 bytes)
            writer.Write((long)score);

            // Write float (4 bytes)
            writer.Write((float)freq);

            // I can even write string on it easily (assuming username string is 2 chars)
            writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username));

            // The stream position should be
            // 2 + 4 + 8 + 4 + 2 = 20
            Console.WriteLine(ms.Position.ToString());

            // Send data to server
            socket.Send(ms.GetBuffer());
        }
```

In C#, I could handle it easily with following code (the code is also similar like send data too):

```
        // Receiving data from the Server
        byte[] resp;
        socket.Receive(out resp);

        // Could be handled with Memory Stream too
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(resp))
        {
            // This time i will use BinaryReader
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(ms);

            // Read int16 (2 bytes)
            short id = reader.ReadInt16();

            // Read int32 (4 bytes)
            int status = reader.ReadInt32();

            // Read int64 (8 bytes)
            long score = reader.ReadInt64();

            // Read float (4 bytes)
            float freq = reader.ReadSingle();

            // Read String (assuming data is 2 bytes)
            string username = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(2));

            // Same like before
            // The stream position should be
            // 2 + 4 + 8 + 4 + 2 = 20
            Console.WriteLine(ms.Position.ToString());
        }
```

but how i can parse it in NodeJS?
can someone tell me which classes in NodeJS that i should use to achieve this? (providing an example like I did in C# is much more appreciated)

any ideas?
sorry for my bad English, thanks in advance

**EDIT**
So I figured a bit, it seem received data is a `Buffer` object as default (thanks for @dandavis)
here my attempt and its working:

```
    // When Server Received data from Client.
    socket.on('data', function(resp) {
      // It's kinda hard (not effective(?))
      // since i need to specify offset each time im trying to read something

      // probably i will write simple class, or does anyone know class
      // that could handle like BinaryReader in C#?

      // Read int16 (2 bytes)
      var id = resp.readInt16LE(0);

      // Read int32 (4 bytes)
      var status = resp.readInt32LE(2);

      // I don't know how to read int64
      var score = // there is no readInt64LE ??

      // Read float (4 bytes)
      var freq = resp.readFloat(14);

      // Read string, assuming encoded with utf8 with 2 characters
      var username = resp.toString('utf8', 18, 2);
    });
```

But there are few problem:

- I don't know how to read (and write) int64
- in API doc, it's doesn't describe what the difference between LE and BE (i can only speculate it was Little Endian and Big Endian, but i don't know them)

Could you guys tell me how to read int64 and give short explanation about LE and BE?

thanks!

Comment: binary socket messages arrive as Buffers, which have an api documented

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness explains Little-Endian vs. Big-Endian.